# Clarify Right hand Rule

Tags: cross-product

I was just wondering whether in the right hand rule are all 3 vectors perpendicular to one another or is it simply one way, i.e. $A \times B=C$, would it be right to also say $C \times A=B$ and $C \times B=A$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $a$ and $b$, $a\times b$ is perpendicular to both $a$ and $b$ regardless of whether $a$ and $b$ are perpendicular. The right-hand rule imposes an orientation on which direction is "up" and how the vectors are oriented relative to one another. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) and [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Right-HandRule.html).

[image]

So, from your example, if we know $c$ and $a$, then we know what direction $c\times a$ points relative to $c$ and $a$, by following the right hand rule.

Similarly, given $c$ and $b$, we know what direction $c\times b$ points relative to $c$ and $b$.

Comment: Does this mean $A$ and $B$ dont have to be perpendicular to one another??

Comment: That is correct. You can cross any two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The right-hand rule *orients* the resulting cross product *relative* to the two vectors you crossed (where the order in which you crossed them *matters*)).

Comment: Accept but no upvote? ;-(