# Visualizing orientation preserving coordinate changes

Tags: differential-geometry, jacobian

On page-50 of Pavel Grinfeld's Tensor Calculus Book, it is said that a change of coordinates is classified in the following way according to the determinant of the jacobian $J$ denoted as $|J|$:

Locally orientation preserving if: $|J|>0$

Locally orientation reversing if : $|J|<0$

But what's the significance of this?

Comment: It just describes the difference between "the right-hand rule" and "the left-hand rule."

Comment: I think a picture would be insightful @DavidG.Stork

Comment: Picture here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792200/clarify-right-hand-rule make your own for left-hand rule.